# Move lines to new file sed, awk or something else

Tags: linux

original text file:

```
some line
a&/\t.sul
a&/\t.sul-aaa
a&/\t.sul*aaa
:_-';".sul
:_-';".sul-aaa
:_-';".sulDaaa
other line
more lines
```

I want to move de lines containing `a&/\t.sul` to a newly to created file called `a&slash\t.sul` (/in a file name is not posible?)

and

the lines with  `:_-';".sul` to a newly to created file called `:_-';".sul`

The original file should look like:

```
some line
other line
more lines
```

I know to escape a special character but this file has a ton of them. I'm looking for something to put in a string I guess.

I spent two days looking for a solution but no joy

Comment: Please, fix english and code block `{}`

Comment: Please include what you've tried.

Comment: Would you prefer sed or grep?

Comment: **move de lines** ???

Comment: You want to create a file `:_-';".sul` ? Wow, what's the point ?

Comment: `pathchk -p ":_-';\".sul"` gives : 
`pathchk: nonportable character ':' in file name ':_-'\'';".sul'`

Comment: Sorry, English is not my base language. The code block looks fine to me but then again this is my first post so sorry if its wrong.

Comment: The point of creating a file like :_-';".sul is so I know it has all the lines containing that phrase without the need for opening it.

Comment: Indeed pathchk give a error but it creates the file just fine, don't know why it say  "nonportable character". Beside you have a \ to much in your try, never the less it also creates that file just fine. The only problem is / witch is reserved for directory.

Comment: Those filenames... For a moment I thought you might be trying to trick us into launching forkbombs on our own systems. Anyway, you are combining the problem of sifting a file with the problem of directing text to files with strange names. Try them separately, and tell us which one you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to move first line to second line

sed  -n '/a\&/!p'  filename

Comment: I don't want to move first line to second line. Your command just deletes "more lines" and prints to terminal. I can not put it better as I did in the question...